# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'ClientUser' object has no attribute 'create_dm'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This command is supposed to DM everyone in a server. Heres my code:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = prefix)
@bot.command(name = 'massdm', pass_context=True)
async def dm(ctx, message):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    for member in guild.members:
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        await member.send(message)
        await ctx.send("Sent message")
```

Comment: Instead of saying getting error you should add the error message to your post.

Comment: ^^^ it didn't give me any error message in the console

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your error but I assume that the line `await ctx.send_message(member, message)` causing the error. There nothing like `ctx.send_message`. You can use `ctx.send`, `channel.send`, `member.send`. If you want to send a dm, you use `member.send`. So you can do:

```py
@bot.command(name = 'massdm', pass_context=True)
async def dm(ctx, message):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    for member in guild.members:
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        try:
            await member.send(message)
            await ctx.send("Sent message")
        except:
            await ctx.send("Error")
```

Comment: Changed my code a bit and now I'm getting a new error message. It's written above if you would like to take a look.

Comment: Can you add how you define the `bot` in your question?

Comment: yeah, added it.

Comment: Can you change the parameter name to something else than `message` or can you change the `guild=ctx.message.guild` to `guild=ctx.guild`?

Comment: same error discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'ClientUser' object has no attribute 'create_dm'