# Direct Message Members of a Discord Guild returns into an error

Tags: python, discord.py

Trying to make a command that direct message all members of a guild in discord, using python.
The error that I'm having it's this:
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'ClientUser' object has no attribute 'dm_channel'`
Here is my code:

```py
@bot.command()
async def dmall(ctx, *, msg):
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        if member.dm_channel is not None:
            await member.dm_channel.send(msg)
        else:
            await member.create_dm()
            await member.dm_channel.send(msg)
    print("sent message to all guild members.")
```

It's very strange for me, because this command used to work some months ago, and also the attribute of "`member.create_dm()`" is mentioned in the documentation. I have another project, using a selfbot that dm specific users and it worked with the `member.create_dm` part. 
Also, I tried this code:

```py
@bot.command()
async def dmall(ctx, *, msg):
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        dm_channel = await member.create_dm()
        await dm_channel.send(msg)
```

But I got the same error, `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'ClientUser' object has no attribute 'create_dm'`
Also, I tried using the `ctx.guild.fetch_members` but I got the same error.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Remember to not abuse this, as **abusing this is a banable offense according to [Discord's TOS](https://discord.com/terms)**

Below is the code that can be used, which should be pretty straight-forward.

```py
@bot.command()
async def dmall(ctx, arg):
    for m in bot.get_all_members():
        await m.send(f"{ctx.message.author} : {arg}")
```

Comment: Returns the same error: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'ClientUser' object has no attribute 'create_dm'`. Maybe the `create_dm` attribute has been removed?

Comment: Have a look at this link, this person was having a similar problem. Compare your code with theirs and others and see if the error changes.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64378414/discord-ext-commands-errors-commandinvokeerror-command-raised-an-exception-att